# While Loop doesn't loop through all 7 cases

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I got case 1-3 working, but I cant get 4-7 working or don't know how I would type it or approach it.

As you can see in number 4 I programmed so when I run the program and press 4 it should run case 4 count down to 10 but skip 7 why wont it work? Also cant figure out how to do 5-7.

I haven't learned that far yet if could help me and also explain how your code works out the problem for me it would be really appropriated.

```
namespace WhileLoopExercises
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int selection = 0;
            while (selection != 9)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n Menu:\n");

                Console.WriteLine("\t 1. Display 10 stars( one per line)");
                Console.WriteLine("\t 2. Request a value 1 to 50 from user, then display");
                Console.WriteLine("\t 3. Display 10 rows of 3 stars");
                Console.WriteLine("\t 4. Add all values between 1 to 10 except 7");
                Console.WriteLine("\t 5. Display all the even numbers between 10 and 100");
                Console.WriteLine("\t 6. Add all the odd numbers bewteen 10 and 100");
                Console.WriteLine("\t 7. Generate 6 random numbers ranging from 1 to 49");
                Console.WriteLine("\t 8. Exit Apllication");

                Console.Write("Enter your selection: ");
                selection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (selection)
                {
                    case 1:
                        {
                            int counter = 1;
                            while (counter <= 10)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("*");
                                counter++;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        {
                            Console.Write("Enter integer 0-50 : ");
                            int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                            int counter = 1;
                            while (counter <= N)
                            {
                                Console.Write("*");
                                counter++;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        {
                            int counter = 1;
                            while (counter <= 10)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("***");
                                counter++;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        {
                            int counter = 1;
                            while (counter <= 10)
                            {
                                if (counter == 7)
                                {

                                    counter++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        {
                            int counter = 1;
                            while (counter <= 100)
                            {

                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        {
                        }
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        {


                        }
                        break;

                }// end of switch
                //pause
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nHit any key to coutinue");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C# != C != C++. Please pick **only** the language tags that are applicable to your question, instead of randomly grabbing the ones that start with the first letter.

Comment: the syntax is so close what does it matter? I mean with the if statement

Comment: btw, if this is homework, you may want to correct `"\n\nHit any key to coutinue"` to `"\n\nHit any key to continue"` ;)

Comment: @davidbro wait whats the different? and no its not homework its an exercise :)

Comment: `coutinue` vs `continue`

Comment: @davidsbro oh snap I might be blind lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 4 won't work as is since it will only increment when `counter` is 7. So it stays infinitely at 1. This should work (without the line numbers at the start - they're for a section below):

```
1  int counter = 1;
2  int sum = 0;             // Need to maintain sum
3  while (counter <= 10) {  // Do all numbers 1 thru 10
4      if (counter != 7)    // Skip 7
5          sum += counter; 
6      counter++;
7  }
8  Console.Write (sum);
```

A similar approach can be taken with all the other cases. All you have to do is figure out exactly what it's asking and map that to code. Try something to see if it works and, if not, run the code through your head to see where it's going wrong. During the learning process, being able to emulate a computer in your head is a valuable skill to learn.

It's often advantageous to sit down with a pencil and paper and run each line in turn (with line numbers matching those in the code above):

```
line | counter | sum | comment
-----+---------+-----+--------
   1 |       1 |   ? |
   2 |         |   0 |
   3 |         |     | 1 <= 10, will enter 'while'
   4 |         |     | 1 != 7, will enter 'if'
   5 |         |   1 |
   6 |       2 |     |
   7 |         |     | return to while loop start
   3 |         |     | 2 <= 10, will enter 'while'
   :
```

and so on.

---

Another example of mapping the requirements to code comes from case 6: `Add all the odd numbers between 10 and 100`. This can be achieved thus:

- the first odd number > 10 is `11`.
- each subsequent odd number is two more than the previous.
- you loop until you're greater than `100`.

That would lead to the following pseudo-code:

```
set sum to 0
set num to 11
while num is less than or equal to 100:
    add num to sum
    add 2 to num
output sum
```

I'll leave converting that to a real language as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me I cant thank you enough.

Answer (score 7):

We can't do your homework for you on stack overflow. However, we can point out your logical issues.

Looking at case four, we see

```
                case 4:
                    {
                        int counter = 1;
                        while (counter <= 10)
                        {
                            if (counter == 7)
                            {
                                counter++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Walk through the problem now. We start with a counter of 1, and while it is less than or equal to 10, we enter your if statement.

Your if statement says "If my counter is equal to seven, then increment (increase) the counter by one." However, your counter enters at 1, and there is no other logic defining the counter's behavior, so nothing happens! This loop then goes on forever (Oops!). With this in mind, try solving again.

Comment: how do you know this is homework? is this a standard lesson in every school? will one successful homework assignment really matter if the user doesn't actually learn anything?

Comment: @RadioSpace There are a number of context clues that suggest it is homework, including the namespace 'WhileLoopExercises', the mention that the user has not learned much, and the fact that it is a program clearly designed to test a student's understanding of while loops. As for whether homework is important, what encouragement is there for a student to try if people will just readily do his (or her) work for him? In not providing the answer directly, the goal is to encourage the student to learn the material, rather than just ask the internet for answers.

Comment: Even if the kind folk at stackoverflow did not give the user the answers. and the 'student' did the required research for the subject at hand. The internet would still give the answer. personally I would like to see people say that this is not a reusable question. as in it is not usefull to anyone but the user. especially since the question title would not lead many people to answers about while loops.

Comment: Its not hw its and exercise I do not get points doing this the only thing I gain is knowledge thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Here are some suggestions for number 4, without just writing the solution:

- Your counter starts at 1, the loop continues while `counter <= 10`, but you only increment it if `counter == 7`. Does that seem like a problem?
- You're doing something when `counter == 7`, but in fact "7" is the only time you *don't* want to be doing anything.
- You need to create another variable to store your "sum" in, then add each value to it.

Comment: Oh my Idea was when it hit seven it adds 1 so it naturally skips it lol

Answer (score 2):

Linq lets you express code in much more compact and readable way.

```
 case 4:
    Console.Write (Enumerable.Range(1,100).Where(v => v != 42).Sum());
```

If you need more basic code consider `for` instead of `while` as it represent iteration over ranges in more idiomatic way (and `continue` is likely what you are expected to use for 4 to skip numbers):

```
 case 4:
    {
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        if (i != 3) 
          continue;
        sum += 0;
    }
    break;
    }
```

Comment: This must be some _new_ definition of the word "readable" of which I was previously unaware :-) Just kidding.